# Assign a client to multiple tags

Tags: awesome

Obviously it is possible to move a client window to another tag but is it possible to assign a client window to multiple tags?

Consider the case having a small floating window which is toggled to keep it on top. I want to assign it to all tags so its visible regardless of the active tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client property is called `sticky`. [Link](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/classes/client.html#client.sticky) to awesome documentation. Add this to your `rc.lua`:

```
    awful.key({ modkey, "Control" }, "s",      function (c) c.sticky = not c.sticky          end,
          {description="toggle sticky", group="client"}),
```